# I want to set the image to match with Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I create a table to show a picture of my friend and me but I can't get my friend picture in data_source and show my picture only.

First, I get picture form Datasource of google (Gmail profile picture) and I use filters like this

```
var empsDS = app.datasources.CurrentUser;
var email = widget.parent.datasource.item.Email;
empsDS.query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals= email;
empsDS.load();
```

but program show my picture only

P.S. This is code to get a picture

```
@datasources.CurrentUser.item.ThumbnailPhotoUrl !== null ? @datasources.CurrentUser.item.ThumbnailPhotoUrl : window.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL
```

Image Ex.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COwmw.png)

Comment: Please explain your question properly, also share code snippets that can help us

Comment: You might want to take a look at your binding to get the picture. Whenever you use `@datasources.CurrentUser.item` you are pointing at the currently selected item in that datasource, which by default is the first item returned from the server. Also, it is unclear if your first code block even returns more than one result which would further complicate things. Is your CurrentUser datasource based on the directory?

Comment: Markus Malessa In the table I will use 2 datasource. profile picture form googleSQL and other data in my SQL. and I filtered by E-mail (Email in google SQL and Email in my SQL). how I filter picture form googleSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it shows only your picture is because your datasource points to only the current user. you need to get the directory and find matches to the emails in order to get the each picture.